# Assembly call memory address

Tags: pointers, assembly, call

This is probally a really stupid question but how do you call a memory address in ASM? I am using the code call dword 557054 (557054 is were code is located...) but I figure that it is calling 557054 + were ever the program got loaded into into memory. I need this for my executable loader...

Comment: Specifically what architecutre? x86, SPARC, PPC, etc...?

Comment: x86 using nasm assembler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to do this, you can use `CALL` or you can use `JMP`, the second is more flexible but requires you to do a little more work if you want some compatibility with C-style code

Simple c-function call using `CALL`

```
push eax ; push args to stack
push ebx
call my_func ; my_func can be a c exported function or defined as a macro or asm function
```

Comment: Thanks lol it turns out my code wasn't working because the linker was messing the function pointer address.

Comment: That tends to happen when something isnt externed (with C code) or not declared global correctly sometimes.